# Can't understand how reactivity and stores work

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm trying to understand how reactivity should work, but I cannot figure out why some things work how they work.

Svelte REPL with the code: https://svelte.dev/repl/aa0821cd95c54708b2d12a05bf74577e?version=3.49.0

I created a simple app:

**App.svelte**:

```js
<script>
    import { numbers } from './store.js'
    
    function copy() {
        $numbers.copied = $numbers.selected
    }
    
    function select(i) {
        console.log("Selected: " + i)
        $numbers.selected = i
    }
</script>

<button on:click={select(1)}>
    1
</button>
<button on:click={select(2)}>
    2
</button>
<button on:click={select(3)}>
    3
</button>

<button on:click={copy()}>
    Copy
</button>

<h1>
    Selected: {$numbers.selected}
</h1>
<h1>
    Copied: {$numbers.copied}
</h1>
```

**store.js**:

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

export let numbers = writable({
    selected: null,
    copied: null
})
```

From this, I was expecting:

1. On launch, store values stay as null
2. On every button click, `$store.selected` changes to proper value
3. `$store.copied` updates its value only when Copy button is clicked

Instead:

1. On launch, `select` function is called 3 times, once for every button with its argument
2. `$store.selected` and `$store.copied` both have value 3 which cannot be changed by clicking buttons
3. When clicking buttons, `select` function is not called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event handlers are just wrong. You are calling the functions instead of passing them.

You need something like `on:click={() => select(1)}`. For `copy` you could also pass it as is because it has no arguments: `on:click={copy}`.